# Copy Word Paragraph to Excel Cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy Word paragraphs to Excel cells, but I am hung up on
Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range.

I have searched. Everything I read says it cannot find the file, but the file is in the same folder, and the name is not mis-spelled, and the extension is correct.  So, I am stumped.  The original code comes from here: [How to copy a formatted paragraph from Word 2013 to Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607961/how-to-copy-a-formatted-paragraph-from-word-2013-to-excel).

```
    Private Sub Load_Schedule()
    Dim ParaCount As Integer
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set wb = Workbooks("new.xlsm")        
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ws.Activate
        ws.Columns(1).AutoFit
    For ParaCount = 1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count
        wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
        Sheets(ws).Cells(ParaCount, 1).PasteSpecial 
        Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next ParaCount
    End Sub
```

The error comes on this line: Set wb = Workbooks("new.xlsm")

Comment: If `"new.xlsm"` isn't open (and open in the *same* instance of Excel Application) at runtime, this error is expected. Try `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("new.xlsm")`.

Comment: It's also not clear where you have instantiated `Excel.Application` class to begin with, assuming this code is running in Word, you need to handle the Excel application.

Comment: new.xlsm is open, and in the same folder.  Closing it and running Set wb = Workbooks.Open("new.xlsm"). produced the same error. What would the code be to instantiate the Excel.Application class,please?

Comment: I changed the code as follows:  Private Sub Load_Schedule()
    Dim ParaCount As Integer
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook 'Object
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Dim str_Excel_Filename As String
    str_Excel_Filename = "new.xlsm"   It says We could'nt find new.xlsm. Is it possible it has been moved or deleted?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Since you have new.xlsm open try vTemp = ActiveWorkbook.name, hover over vTemp in debug and see what the name is.

Comment: `Dim excel as New Excel.Application` and `Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("new.xlsm")`.

Comment: Where do you run this code? Excel or Word? In Excel's VBA you don't need an extra reference to `Excel.Application`.

Comment: Try providing the full path + filename. You shouldn't *need* to do this, but it's worth trying anyways. It's possible your word macro resides in your Normal.dot file isntead of the docx? That might explain the failure with relative path.

Comment: @Asger `ActiveDocument` without a qualifier implies this must be run from Word, so a reference to Excel Application should be necessary.

Comment: @David No. I just tested it.

Comment: @Asger fair. also notice the expliict declarations of the `Word` types, so must be run from Excel I guess. My bad! Error might also happen if running this macro from an unsaved Workbook (in which case there is no path./relative path). Always safer to use fully qualified file paths.

Comment: Chas, please use the [edit] link below the question to inlcude additional information (such as "I changed the code...") in the question, itself. The idea behind Stack overflow is to provide a Q&A source that benefits *everyone*, so it's important that all pertinent information is in the question, not in comments that need to be sifted through.

Answer (score 1):

As you work with both applications, you should use full declarations like `Word.Document` and `Excel.Workbook` (if you already referenced the appropriate libraries).

An already opened Excel file can be referenced without path.

The `Paste:= ...` parameter belongs to the previous code line, so you have to add a blank + undersore at the end of the previous line or put them together into one line.

Please reference your worksheet's cell by `ws.Cells ...` and not by `Sheets(ws)`, as your "ws" already is a worksheet object and not a string.

The further answer depends, if you run your code from Word-VBA or from Excel-VBA.

---

#### Word VBA

If you want to reference an Excel file from Word-VBA, you need the Excel.Application object additionally.
If Excel is already started, you can use the existing application object - otherwise you create one and make it visible.

Same with your Excel file: If it's already open, you use it - if not, you open it.

```
Private Sub LoadSchedule()
    Dim ParaCount As Integer
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks("new.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objExcel.DefaultFilePath & "\new.xlsm")
        ' or ThisDocument.Path or whatever path
    End If
    
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For ParaCount = 1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count
        wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
        ws.Cells(ParaCount, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next ParaCount
    
    ws.Columns(1).AutoFit
    'ws.Activate
End Sub
```

---

#### Excel VBA

In Excel you can try to reference an already opened Word file directly as `ActiveDocument` without getting the Word.Application additionally.

```
Private Sub LoadSchedule()
    Dim ParaCount As Integer
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("new.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Application.DefaultFilePath & "\new.xlsm")
    End If
    
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For ParaCount = 1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count
        wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
        ws.Cells(ParaCount, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next ParaCount
    
    ws.Columns(1).AutoFit
    'ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to hear that my code worked nicely. Then please mark my answer as "accepted answer" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I first hit an 'new.xlsm does not exist, could it be removed or renamed' 'Error, so created an empty 'new,xlsm' file. After that, It runs till the for loop, then says 'Error 1004 VBA PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed' .

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the full path to the excel file - you say it's the same as the word document so this will work:

```
Sub GetXLFileInWord()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = xl.Documents.Open(ThisDocument.Path & "\new.xlsm")
```

Comment: Yes.  Asger's code worked nicely. I did have to specify the full path as Harassed  Dad said.  I also changed folder names having spaces to names with underscores between words.