# VBA copying MS Word paragraphs to Excel, Error 1004 PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, ms-word, paste

Building on the question asked in [Copy Word Paragraph to Excel Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494639/copy-word-paragraph-to-excel-cells) , I am trying to paste paragraphs in a file in the first sheet of an excel workbook, columns 1,2,3,4, based on whether the paragraph style is heading1, heading2, heading3, or heading4.

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub LS2()
    Dim ParaCount As Integer
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If objExcel Is Nothing Then
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks("new.xlsm")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aesnj\OneDrive\Desktop\FPR\new.xlsm")
    End If
    
    Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For ParaCount = 1 To wDoc.Paragraphs.Count
        If wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading1 Then
            wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
            ws.Cells(ParaCount, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        ElseIf wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading2 Then
            wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
            ws.Cells(ParaCount, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        ElseIf wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading3 Then
            wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
            ws.Cells(ParaCount, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        ElseIf wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.Style = wdStyleHeading4 Then
            wDoc.Paragraphs(ParaCount).Range.FormattedText.Copy
            ws.Cells(ParaCount, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next ParaCount
    ws.Columns(1).AutoFit

End Sub
```

However, I first faced the error:  `'new.xlsm does not exist, could it be removed or renamed'` 'Error, so created an empty 'new,xlsm' file. After that, It runs till the for loop, then says `'Error 1004 VBA PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed'` . I tried adding 'Option Explicit' at the top of the file, no luck. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Since this is hosted in Word, `xlPasteFormats` is unknown and without `Option Explict` will be automatically Dim'd as Variant and default to `0`.  Replace it with its [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)  (may or may not be your whole issue).  Note that if it works, this will paste _only_ the Formatting.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - OP is using early binding...

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks very much for your answer,  I did replace xlPasteFormat with xlPasteValues and added Option Explicit at the top, also removed 'Private' and tried both, no luck

Comment: @tim, yes, but that's not relevant to my comment.   IIRC you can't access an Enumeration from an early bound library.   I'm not by a PC with Office ATM, can you verify or disprove my assertion?

Comment: @chrisneilsen  - early binding gives you access to the constants defined in the referenced library